# Unexplained shoots sprouting

Tags: pruning

I have a weeping mulberry non-fruit bearing that has a few new shoots sprouting out of the top that have diff leaves that appear lobbed. These new shoots do not weep down like the rest of the tree, and it branches from  the trunk itself. I understand this could be from the grafting. My question is should these shoots be trimmed? The tree looks odd with this crazy sprouting area pointing upward. Can someone help with ideas please?

Thank you kindly, LLE

Comment: Please [edit] in some pictures of the issue, if you can manage that. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Weeping mulberries only weep because they are grafted, often onto an ordinary white mulberry. The graft will be at the base of the weeping growth where it joins the top of the main trunk, so it sounds like you have growth off the trunk of the lower part, which you do not want.  Remove them at their point of origin off the main trunk as neatly as possible. Unfortunately, now this has started to happen, it  will likely recur, but remove them as soon as you notice the shoots. https://homeguides.sfgate.com/propagation-weeping-mulberry-100719.html

Answer (score 0):

If the new shoots are growing from the trunk, then they're below the graft and therefore not from the weeping form of the tree. You should always prune these out because their natural inclination is to form an upright tree. Over time, this will out-compete the weeping form of the tree.